# WPF White screen and 1 GB of umanaged RAM usage on Windows 8.1 and Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with WPF Application. It runs perfectly on Windows 10, tested on latest update 1803 and latest Insider Fast, but when application is run on Windows 8 or 7, application starts, uses 1 GB of unamanged RAM for few milliseconds and then renders only white screen. App is running and I can see cursor changing and code running in background, but when I try to move Window for example, application crashes with Out Of Memory exception and Application does not have enough memory to execute.
I do not understand this problem, I tried removing code from it... It can be libraries or XAML.
I tried different .NET versions. I am out of ideas.
Did anyone ever had this problem? How to solve it? I can publish code if required to get help... I am really lost.

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindow" x:Class="GameV2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GameV2"
        xmlns:GameEngine="clr-namespace:GameEngine;assembly=GameEngineV2"
        xmlns:zp="clr-namespace:ZoomAndPan;assembly=ZoomAndPan"
        mc:Ignorable="d" TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}" Background="Black"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="640" Width="1280" PreviewKeyDown="mainWindow_PreviewKeyDown">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <materialDesign:DialogHost IsTabStop="False">
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1">
                    <zp:ZoomAndPanControl UseAnimations="True" MinimumZoomType="FitScreen" ZoomAndPanInitialPosition="FitScreen" x:Name="zoomBorder">
                    <Grid x:Name="maingrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                    </Grid>
                    </zp:ZoomAndPanControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <!--GUI-->
                <Grid Panel.ZIndex="3">
                    <!--TOP PANEL-->
                    <Grid x:Name="menuControlGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Panel.ZIndex="9999" Background="#99000000" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="485"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="250"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="195"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="menuButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,5,10" Width="30" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Grid.Column="2" Click="menuButton_Click"/>
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,5,10" Width="30" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="2" Source="Resources/Icons/menu.png" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="buildButton" Content="BUILD" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-30,10,0,10" Width="105" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignRaisedLightButton}" Grid.Column="2" Checked="buildButton_Checked" Unchecked="buildButton_Unchecked"/>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,7,0,3" Width="105" Grid.Column="0">
                            <materialDesign:Card >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Icons/Status/happy.png" Margin="5,0,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap" Cursor="Arrow"  Text="65 535" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40,5,0,5" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFont}" FontWeight="DemiBold"></TextBox>
                                </Grid>
                            </materialDesign:Card>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,7,0,3" Width="155" Grid.Column="0">
                            <materialDesign:Card>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Icons/balance.png" Margin="5,0,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Cursor="Arrow"  Text="2 147 483 647" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40,5,0,5" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFont}" FontWeight="DemiBold" />
                                </Grid>
                            </materialDesign:Card>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,7,0,3" Width="115" Grid.Column="0">
                            <materialDesign:Card >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Icons/profit.png" Margin="5,0,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Cursor="Arrow"  Text="999 999" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40,5,0,5" Width="60" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFont}" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </materialDesign:Card>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="395,7,0,3" Width="85" Grid.Column="0">
                            <materialDesign:Card >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Icons/quests.png" Margin="5,0,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Cursor="Arrow"  Text="255" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40,5,0,5" Width="30" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFont}" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </materialDesign:Card>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Margin="25.2,7,25.4,3" Grid.Column="1">
                            <materialDesign:Card >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Icons/calendar.png" Margin="5,0,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap" x:Name="clockText" Cursor="Arrow"  Text="{Binding Path=ClockMessageText, ElementName=mainWindow}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40,5,0,5" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFont}" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="6,6,6,6" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="170,5,5,5">
                                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="18*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="16*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Rectangle Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="0" />
                                            <Rectangle Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="1" />
                                            <Rectangle Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="2" />
                                            <Rectangle Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="3" />
                                            <Rectangle Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="4" />
                                            <Rectangle Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="5" />
                                            <Rectangle Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="6" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </materialDesign:Card>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Path Width="10" Height="10" Margin="500.35,49.75,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#99000000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" IsHitTestVisible="False" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" Figures="M 10,0 5,0 Q 0,0 0,5 L 0,10 L 0,0 L 10,0" />
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Width="10" Height="10" Margin="656,50,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#99000000" IsHitTestVisible="False" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" Figures="M 10,0 5,0 Q 0,0 0,5 L 0,10 L 0,0 L 10,0" />
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0,0,9,9" Margin="510,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Width="146" Background="#99000000" Panel.ZIndex="10000" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
                        <Grid x:Name="menuTimeGrid">
                            <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="28" Width="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Button x:Name="pause" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Width="26" Height="26" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" Click="pause_Click"/>
                                <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/Time/pause.png"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Margin="43,0,0,0" Height="28" Width="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Button x:Name="play" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" Width="26" Height="26" Click="play_Click"/>
                                <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/Time/Play.png"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Margin="76,0,0,0" Height="28" Width="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Button x:Name="playFast" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Width="26" Height="26" Click="playFast_Click"/>
                                <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/Time/fast.png"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Margin="109,0,0,0" Height="28" Width="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Button x:Name="playFastest" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Width="26" Height="26" Click="playFastest_Click"/>
                                <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/Time/fastest.png"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <!--RIGHT PANEL-->
                    <Grid x:Name="buildGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50,0,0" Width="220" Visibility="Hidden">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100px"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="buttonsBorder" Grid.Row="0"  Background="#99000000" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0,0,0,9">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Width="100" Height="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="130.5,49,-10,49" TextWrapping="NoWrap" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsEnabled="False" Cursor="Arrow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                    <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </TextBox.RenderTransform>
                                </TextBox>
                                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="roadButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="RoadButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/road.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="structureButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="StructureButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/foundaments.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="wallButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="WallButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/walls.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="objectButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="ObjectButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/objects.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="floorButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="FloorButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/floors.png" ></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="zoneButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="ZoneButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/Planning.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="disRoadButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="DisRoadButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/noroad.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="disStructureButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="DisStructureButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/nofoundaments.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="disWallButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="DisWallButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/nowalls.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="disObjectButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="DisObjectButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/noobjects.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="disFloorButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="DisFloorButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/nofloors.png" ></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Button x:Name="assignJobButton" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Click="AssignJobButton_Click"/>
                                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="Resources/Icons/RightPanel/Assigment.png"></Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="contentBorder" Grid.Row="1" Background="#99000000" Visibility="Hidden">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="buildMenuContent"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <Path Height="10" Margin="0,50,220,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#99000000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" IsHitTestVisible="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="10" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=buildGrid, Path=Visibility}" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" Figures="M 10,0 5,0 Q 0,0 0,5 L 0,10 L 0,0 L 10,0" />
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="{Binding Path=DayNightBrush, ElementName=mainWindow}" Opacity="{Binding Path=DayNightOpacity, ElementName=mainWindow}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

And background code https://pastebin.com/gbBqLeWH

Comment: We need a minimal code example

Comment: Maybe change your target SDK.

Comment: We only know what you tell us. As it is it's anyone's guess what code you have. Are you using any win10 specific stuff?

Comment: Added my code, hope it helped.

Comment: Lowering resolution helped to run app on Windows 8.1. Is it running out of graphical memory? If yes, why? Why is it not swaping on RAM? And why it works in WIndows 10?

Answer (score -1):

You must have set these two properties to your `Window`:

```
window.AllowsTransparency = true;
window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
```

This two properties will change your window into a layered window and will take much more memory than a normal one.

If you have done so, remove it. If you want a custom title bar, try to use a `WindowChrome`.

Read more about window style customize using `WindowChrome`:

- [WindowChrome Class (System.Windows.Shell) - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [WPF 使用 WindowChrome，在自定义窗口标题栏的同时最大程度保留原生窗口样式（类似 UWP/Chrome） - walterlv](https://walterlv.com/post/wpf-simulate-native-window-style-using-window-chrome.html)